# Does the gravitational constant $G$ vary with temperature?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, temperature, physical-constants

Recently I encountered a question that was Does the gravitational constant $G$ vary with temperature? I think it should not but I am not sure about it? why does it vary?

Comment: Can you link or quote a bit from where you read this?

Comment: I saw a person questioning it and I was confused to read it.I searched it on Google but came no useful results.

Comment: Do you mean the Universal Gravitational constant, G, or local acceleration due to gravity, g ?

Comment: I mean Gravitational constant G.

Comment: There is no direct relation in the mainstream physics, but gravity and thermodynamics is a popular thing today, and you may have read or heard some interesting article. If you didn't, the answer is simply "no". If you did, your question an interesting one and you may get a high level answer from a physicist. This is why a link or some info would be important for your question.

Comment: @SaraAsfar: What person? Where? When?

Comment: At another site but this is unnecessary to be known.@Kyle Kanos

Comment: Temperature _of what_?

Comment: @sara-asfar It is usual on this website to post links (or references) to the sources of your question and it's basis.  If a user asks for such a link, please provide it to help them.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really know how to post a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it: how would you measure such a variation? You could think of a balance experiment along the following lines, which, in passing, was performed by Poyinting and Phillips as early as 1905 [1]. First precisely balance two masses as identical as possible, let's label them as A and B, the two masses being at the same temperature $T$, thus measuring the ratio $m_A(T)g_A(T)/m_B(T)g_B(T)$ where $g_A$ (resp. $g_B$) is the local acceleration of gravity experienced by $A$ (resp. $B$), and those accelerations would be proportional to the gravitational constant for $A$ (resp. $B$). A priori both the masses and the $g$'s depend on temperature. Then heat up mass A to $T'$ while keeping mass B at the same temperature and precisely balance again, thus measuring this time $m_A(T')g_A(T')/m_B(T)g_B(T)$. This experiment can therefore measure ratios $m_A(T')g_A(T')/m_A(T)g_A(T)$. As you can see it is impossible to tell whether $g_A(T)$ effectively varies with temperature, or whether it is $m_A(T)$ that does so, or whether it is a combination of both.

You may then suggest a dynamical experience instead, based on free fall, but then there is no reason to assume that the inertial mass $m_I$ is equal to the gravitational mass $m_G$, if you are willing to admit that $g$ may vary with temperature. Thus the equation of motion would then be, for the position $x$ of the test mass,

$$\ddot{x}=\frac{m_G}{m_I}g$$

Performing the experience with different temperatures $T$ of the mass would tell you how $m_G(T)g(T)/m_I(T)$ vary with the temperature $T$. Again it is impossible to disentangle a variation of $g(T)$ from a variation of the masses.

Perhaps it is my lack of imagination but I do not see any way to escape this issue. Thus I do not know what you read but I think you got mislead.

[1] J. H. Poynting and Percy Phillips
Proceedings of the Royal Society of London. Series A, Containing Papers of a
Mathematical and Physical Character, Vol. 76, No. 512 (Sep. 13, 1905), pp. 445-457

Answer (score -1):

If we think general relativity (the best model of gravity that we currently have):
\begin{equation}
G_{\mu\nu}=8\pi G T_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
I may think of $G$ as (part of) a factor of proportionality relating curvature (e.g. gravity: $G_{\mu\nu}$) and matter/energy distribution ($T_{\mu\nu}$). A change in temperature implies that $T_{\mu\nu}$ changes (somehow, although that calculation would almost certainly be very ugly for most scenarios), which implies that $G_{\mu\nu}$ will change accordingly. However, this constant of proportionality does not change.